# My program run and returns 0, but it doesn't display the cout data ive given it

Tags: c++, math, numbers, cout

When I Build and run my code it instantly returns 0 saying programing was successful, however i want it to display all **the numbers from 100 to 200 that are divisible by 4.**

Here's my code...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int num = 200;
int snum;

cout<<"The following numbers are all divisble by 4 and are inbetween 100 and 200\n";
while(num<99)
{
    snum = (num % 4) ;

    cout<<snum<<endl;
    cout<<num<<endl;

            if(snum = 0)
            {
                cout<< num << endl;
            }
            else
            {

            }
            num--;
}



return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` condition should be `while (num > 99)` instead of `while(num<99)`(false at the beginning)

The `if` condition should be `if (snum == 0)` instead of `if(snum = 0)`(`=` is assignment, not equal operator)

The `else` part has nothing, you may delete it. I added some other notes in the comments below.

```
while (num > 99)
{
    snum = num % 4 ;  // no need for the parenthesizes

    if (snum == 0)
    {
        std::cout<< num << std::endl;
    }
    --num;    //pre-increment is preferred, although doesn't matter in this case
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop never executes because the condition

```
(num<99)
```

is already false from the start. You probably meant

```
(num>99)
```

Also, the if statement condition

```
(snum = 0)
```

sets `snum` to zero, always returning zero, so you probably meant

```
(snum == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `num` to be 200:

```
int num = 200;
```

Then you only run the loop if and when the number is ***less than*** 99:

```
while(num<99)
```

What do you expect will happen?

---

This is ***not*** how you do an equals-test in C:

```
if(snum = 0)
```

In C, equality is checked with `==`:

```
if(snum == 0)
```

In fact, what you have (`if (snum = 0)`) will NEVER be true, so your if-statement will NEVER be executed.